# Jmeter Math Confusion

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jmeter, automated-tests, jmeter-plugins

I have A problem With The Jmeter Tool it dosen't view result i'm testing from my local host and i don't know where is the problem
[This is my Recording templete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOBBV.png)

[And This is my Local Host That I want To test It](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak1L3.png)

I Don't Know What Is The wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to [configure your browser](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-set-proxy-server-all-major-internet-browsers-windows/) to use JMeter as the proxy
2. If you're recording [HTTPS traffic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) you need to import JMeter's certificate, see **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) JMeter User Manual entry for more details
3. In case of any problems check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries

Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates, just follow your test scenario steps in the browser and once done you will be able to export recorded requests in form of JMeter's [.jmx test script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan)